# django filter: How to filter results with multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-filter

I am working on Django and I need to filter records eg:

table: Person

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| David Abraham Benj | 18 |

so, if I run this, `Person.objects.filter(name__icontains="David Abraham")` it is working

but if I run this, `Person.objects.filter(name__icontains="David Benj")` it is not working

any idea how it works?

framework: Django and SQL: Postgres

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) in order to chain multiple SQL `ILIKE` operations, which is what the `__icontains` operator produces in the backgroud.

Try this:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

Person.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains="David") &
    Q(name__icontains="Benj")
)
```

Comment: Good answer, but it could be simpler: `Person.objects.filter(name__icontains="David", name__icontains="Benj")` would work too, since multiple filters are implicitly ANDed together. Would avoid use of Q objects.

Comment: @NickODell I can't test this at the moment, but won't it throw a `SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated`?

Comment: I forgot about that. Good point!

Comment: and it can be dynamically created with `query = Q()` + `query &= Q(name__icontains=loopvar)` *(AND)* or `query |= Q(name__icontains=loopvar)` *(OR)* or even `query |= (Q(name__icontains=loop_firstname) & Q(name__icontains=loop_lastname))` *((first0 AND last0) OR (first1 AND last1)* + `Person.objects.filter(query)` *Q statements are fun :-)*

Answer (score 1):

```
Person.objects.filter(name__icontains="David Benj")
```

Which equal to

```
SELECT ... WHERE name ILIKE '%David Benj%';
```

So, it doesn't match the query. So, it's expected behavior.